# How do I set/get the Phone in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can I set/get the phone through any function?  I want to get phone number for the purpose of sms gateway. Kindly help. I tried searching everywhere and even used

```
echo $woocommerce->customer->get_phone();
echo $woocommerce->customer->get_billing_phone();
```

Answer (score 1):

from the WC_Order object u can access it:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
var_dump($order->billing_phone);
```

should now give you the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```html
 <?php $my_orders_columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', array(
 'order-number'  => __( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ),
 'order-date'    => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
 'order-status'  => __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
 'order-total'   => __( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ),
 'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
) );

$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(

 'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
 'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
 'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
 'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
) ) );

if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>


   <?php foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) :
    $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
    $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
    ?>
    
     <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
     
       <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

       <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
        
       
        
        <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
   <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--phone"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>

      

       <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
       
       <?php endif; ?>
      
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    
   <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$orders = wc_get_orders(
    array(
        'limit' => -1,
    )
);

foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    echo $order->get_billing_phone();
}
```